# Unable to Access CloudSQL MYSQL5.7 From Service Account Using CLI

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy, gcp-iam

I have simple cloudsql instance for MYSQL_5_7 with enable_iam_authentication flag on.

I have added service account or IAM user and want to access the instance using mysql client.

I am using cloudsql auth proxy:

`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=watchful-pier-333707:us-central1:test-002=tcp:3306 --enable_iam_login`

Accessing the DB with below command:
`mysql -u root -p --host 127.0.0.1`

Using Built-in user root I am successfully able to access the instance.

When I am trying to access the DB with IAM user/service account using below command, I am getting  "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0".

`mysql -u <user_name> -p --host 127.0.0.1`
**user_name is the one I can see as added user in user's list**

Following this documentation - [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/add-manage-iam-users#gcloud_1)

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with CLI is using below command:

`` MYSQL_PWD=`gcloud auth print-access-token` mysql --enable-cleartext-plugin  --host=127.0.0.1 --user=<user_name> ``

Make sure you have authorized the service account and gave it token creator role.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic IAM AuthN isn't yet available for MySQL. Once it is, we'll update the [proxy docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#-enable_iam_login).

Comment: Hi @enocom, thanks for confirming the same.
I am now trying to perform manual AuthN with cloudsql proxy. Is there any specific documentation or java example which I can refer.
When I am trying to do so I am facing two issues:
1) getting Auth token from Java Client Lib(using only service account without key.json file).
2) While trying tom connect with DB using 127.0.0.1:3306 for cloudsql auth proxy I am getting this error `ava.sql.SQLException: SSL connection required for plugin "mysql_clear_password". Check if 'sslMode' is enabled.`

Comment: Have you tried following the docs? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/iam-logins#logging-in-as-a-user Since the OAuth2 token is short lived, I'd recommend using traditional authentication if you're using it in a Java application. Otherwise, you'll have to write token refresh logic.

Comment: Yes I have followed the same doc. It's working fine with gcloud cli but  getting error from java application. I am using traditional approach to connect with the DB using 127.0.0.1:3306 to connect with cloudsql proxy.

Comment: If you're trying to use IAM AuthN with the Java connector, it's not supported yet either. The CLI answer you gave above is the easiest approach for simple CLI tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic IAM was not supported on MySQL when you tried this, but it is now

```
$ mkdir -p ~/cloudsql2
$ cloud_sql_proxy --projects my-project -dir ~/cloudsql2 -enable_iam_login
$ mysql -S ~/cloudsql2/my-project\:us-west1\:my-instance-name -u dantest
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6200833
Server version: 5.7.39-google-log (Google)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

See more: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authentication#automatic